# C++98: Compile Time Detect floating point type

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

So you can make a fake is_integral in C++98 with the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_integral
{
  static const bool value;
};

template <typename T>
const bool is_integral<T>::value = std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer;
```

easy enough...is there anything similar you can do for floating point (without getting a boost dependency?)

Comment: Why do you initialize `value` constant outside a class declaration?

Comment: @Constructor I should have used an enum, true. But because the rules for initializing static constant values are not uniform, whenever I use it I initialize outside of the class for consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf)* states:

> Specializations shall be provided for each fundamental type, both floating point and integer, including bool.

(*- I am having trouble finding an earlier draft of the standard. If someone can lend a hand here, it'd be much appreciated.)

Since `std::numeric_limits` provides definitions for `is_integer` and `is_specialized`, you can combine the information to deduce whether or not a type is a floating point type.

For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_floating_point
{
    static const bool value;
};

template <typename T>
const bool is_floating_point<T>::value =
    std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized &&  // Is fundamental arithmetic type...
    !std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer;       // ...that is not an integer
```

Comment: Can you comment on why yours is more valid than lenegds2k?

Comment: They're functionally equivalent, so it really just comes down to personal taste. My approach is standards-focused: "The standard says `std::numeric_limits` is specialized for integral and floating point values. It also defines ways to determine if a type is a specialized type or an integral type, implicitly giving the ability to determine if a type is a floating point type." The approach from @legends2k is math-focused: "A number can be an integer or floating point. Both are bounded (in C++), so if a type isn't an integer it must be a floating point." I'd say use whichever is more intuitive.

Comment: @Lilshieste +1 (both answer & comment) for summarizing it: _My approach is standards-focused; legends2k's is math-focused_

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only three floating point types (per C++98 §3.9.1/8), it's not hard to enumerate them:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_floating_point {
  enum { value = 0 };
};

template <>
struct is_floating_point<float> {
  enum { value = 1 };
};

template <>
struct is_floating_point<double> {
  enum { value = 1 };
};

template <>
struct is_floating_point<long double> {
  enum { value = 1 };
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I went with this on e atm

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of your `is_integral` trick:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct is_floating_point
{
  static const bool value;
};

// is a fundamental type (i.e. not a user defined type) but not an integer
template <typename T>
const bool is_floating_point<T>::value =
!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer && std::numeric_limits<T>::is_bounded;

struct Obj
{
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_floating_point<float>::value << std::endl;        // 1
    std::cout << is_floating_point<int>::value << std::endl;          // 0
    std::cout << is_floating_point<Obj>::value << std::endl;          // 0
    std::cout << is_floating_point<bool>::value << std::endl;         // 0
    std::cout << is_floating_point<double>::value << std::endl;       // 1
    std::cout << is_floating_point<long double>::value << std::endl;  // 1

    // this would compile since it's an array of size 1
    int Y[is_floating_point<float>::value] = { };
    // this wouldn't compile since it's an array of size 0
    int N[is_floating_point<int>::value] = { };
}
```

Comment: Can you comment why yours is more valid than Lishieste's answer?